# Extract certain lines from CLOB column

Tags: oracle11g, clob

I have a CLOB column where there are lines like this:

```
[2019-01-24 11:57:05]: Serial.no is: 12330

[2019-01-24 11:57:05]: Buyers: 3

[2019-01-24 11:57:06]: Serial.no is: 23340

[2019-01-24 11:57:06]: Buyers: 6
```

Now I would like a Select on that column and extract only lines where "Serial.no" is, example:

```
[2019-01-24 11:57:05]: Serial.no is: 12330
[2019-01-24 11:57:06]: Serial.no is: 23340
```

I'm hoping for some easy solution because I don't quite understand everything I found so far, thanks in advance.

EDIT:

This returns me one row, first one:

```
select regexp_substr(My_CLOB, 'Serial.no.*',1) as clob_data from MyTable
WHERE id='1163753';
```

It returns column in CLOB datatype, but that wouldn't be a problem If I could retrieve all rows.

Comment: So the text in the clob has embedded line feeds?

Comment: @OldProgrammer, I don't know exactly but I would say yes, not sure what you mean by this. I edited my answer, brackets in CLOB are exactly same, maybe that tells you anything.

Comment: Maybe someone knows how to insert all lines from CLOB to another table with Varchar column, line by line ? that would solve my problems too, I would just run a query on that table after ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a trick to use the connect by clause to increment the regexp index.  Seems to work

```
WITH test AS (
     SELECT
         '[2019-01-24 11:57:05]: Serial.no is: 12330
[2019-01-24 11:57:05]: Buyers: 3
[2019-01-24 11:57:06]: Serial.no is: 23340
[2019-01-24 11:57:06]: Buyers: 6'
         my_clob
     FROM
         dual
 )
 SELECT
     regexp_substr(my_clob,'Serial.no.*',1,level) AS clob_data
 FROM
     test
 CONNECT BY
     level <= regexp_count(my_clob,'Serial.no.*')
```

Comment: this doesn't work, I think because of **my_clob** Select. What I need is to select my clob first - like "**SELECT clob_column FROM MyTable where id='1163753'**"...When I do that, query result is only 370 rows of CLOB column and each row contains only "**Serial.no**", not the whole line as desired. Maybe I should turn CLOB to Varchar2 in upper Select. And how ?

Comment: It works, my bad. But It returns only string after "Serial.no" till the end of line. How can I fix regexp to include dates in brackets too ?

Comment: nevermind, I fixed everything, I only needed to change this line **(my_clob,'Serial.no.*',1,level)** to **(my_clob,'^.*Serial.no.*$',1,level,'m')**. Many  thanks for all help !